# MySQL OUT parameter returning NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a procedure in MySQL and I want the string Question_Description to be passed as an OUT parameter. However, every time I execute the procedure, it always returns NULL. How do I fix this? I have tried many different methods and none of them have worked.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `QuestionTitle`(IN `QID` INT(11), OUT `Description` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
select Question.Question_ID, Question.Question_Description
FROM Question, QuestionAllocator
WHERE Question.Question_ID=QuestionAllocator.QuestionID and Question.Question_ID=QID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Well, if you don't ever assign a value, what do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `QuestionTitle`(
    IN in_QID INT(11),
    OUT out_Description VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT out_Description := q.Question_Description
    FROM Question q
    WHERE q.Question_ID = in_QID;
END$$
```

Note the other changes:

- The input arguments clearly show they are either in or out parameters.  This helps avoid conflict with column names.
- Only one table is needed, so the other is removed.
- The output parameter is assigned a value.
- You need to learn proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax, even if this query does not require a `JOIN`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the := ?

Comment: @afterwaves . . . That sets the value.  You could alternatively use `into`.

Comment: Thanks, completely new to SQL so this helped.